# Help finding garden hose to kitchen faucet adapter

Tags: hose, adapter

I am having a hard time figuring out which adapter to get to hook my garden hose up to my pull down kitchen faucet. I included some photos, I would appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't looked for an alternate location to connect the hose.?   Why a garden hose inside the house?

Comment: You should not do this. The flexible line in the faucet was not designed to have a long hose connected to it. Also you would have to fit a checkvalve/anti-siphon fitting.

Comment: Can you please expand on why you want to connect a garden hose to your kitchen tap ?  This may be an XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is, you've probably got a proprietary thread on the faucet that isn't going to match anything in a typical plumbing aisle. Your best chance is to find a real plumbing store and visit with parts in hand. (Best case is that you have both sides of that connection, but I understand that it might be bothersome to uninstall the faucet.)

If you could order a replacement spray head from the manufacturer, that (and a lot of epoxy) could be built into an adapter.

Alternately, you could split the water supply after the shutoff under the sink and install a spigot down there. The merits of having an additional point of failure in a cabinet are debatable.

Comment: A plumbing store should be able to match with just the female(just the end) threads.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider attaching garden hose to your water lines for clothes washer using a Y adapter.  It will give you hot water to the hose easier than kitchen sink.  I did this to bathe paralyzed dog on my deck.

Comment: How does this help solve the problem of finding a fitting for their faucet? Wouldn't they have the same problem finding a Y to fit their faucet?